# Ember: how to trigger event when textarea loses focus?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How can I make this textarea trigger an action when it loses focus?

```
{{textarea value=item.text}}
```

I'm guessing that there is a way to do it with custom views but I'm just not able to make sense of it yet.

Comment: im not familiar with ember, but are you not able to use an on blur handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define your actions for those *focus-in, focus-out, key-press, insert-new-line, enter* view events.

{{textarea value=item.text focus-out="validate"}}

This [documentation](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/4755) is missing.